# Secure web application without login/authentication module

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an web application that only is uses intern by employees. Is there a alternative to secure access to this web application without implement login/authentication module? I was thinking about a query parameter key, but it seems ugly.

Comment: You could custom a middleware to judge if the url contains parameter key like:`role=user`.If does not exsit,return 401.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [auth0 Passwordless](https://auth0.com/passwordless). Auth0 purpose a [web kit](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/passwordless#passwordless-on-single-page-apps).

According to the documentation : Passwordless connections allow users to log in **without** the need to remember a **password**. Instead, **users** enter their **mobile phone number or email address** and **receive a one-time code or link**, which they can then **use** to **log in**.